# Query to get a list of unique ID and an additional field from multiple tables SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have got 100s of CSV files with Policy No and Issue Date. I would like identify a list of unique PolicyNo and their corresponding Issue Dates from all the CSV files.

One PolicyNo can appear in multiple files.

If I had say 5 files, I would do a SQL query to UNION all the files and Group By. However as I have more than 100 files, is there a more efficient approach other than Union on 100 files.

Unfortunately, I only have Microsoft Access to solve this issue.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Import the files into a table, then do your select grouping it.

Comment: Access is the best tool for this - use a VBA loop to open and import all the files into one table with your unqiue key(s) and you'll remove all duplicates at once

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. All csv files have the same structure.
2. You have a table named `TempCsvTable` containing the same fields,
   that should contain data from all csv files at the end of the
   process.
3. All csv files to be imported are in one directory (*folder*).
4. No other files are in the above directory (*folder*).

`Private sub ImportCSVs(TempImportFolder as String)

    On Error Resume Next 
    Dim objFS As Object, objFolder As Object, objFiles As Object

    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder((TempImportFolder)) 
    Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
    For Each file In objFiles
        DoCmd.TransferText acLinkDelim, , "TempCsvTable", TempImportFolder & "\" & file.Name, True

        CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM TempCsvTable"
        CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "TempCsvTable"

    Next
End Sub`